Видео в блоках как единое целое
Мне нужно получить решение, где видео будет проигрываться как единое целое, а не случайными кусочками. То есть в этом случае .gap должны быть эдакими окошками, а видео находится за темным фоном.
Пример:



* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.rows {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 110%;
  color: #fff;
}

.gap {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gap video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}
<div class="rows">
        <div class="row">
            we're here
            <div class="gap">
                <video autoplay loop muted>
                    <source
                        src="https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/eg0c3th4vyjnnz09cwxam/22512-328261507_tiny.mp4?rlkey=sk0uvs93a3uby17qbzdx1c3cx&raw=1"
                        type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            to make
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            healthy
            <div class="gap">
                <video autoplay loop muted>
                    <source
                        src="https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/eg0c3th4vyjnnz09cwxam/22512-328261507_tiny.mp4?rlkey=sk0uvs93a3uby17qbzdx1c3cx&raw=1"
                        type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            living effortless,
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            so you can
            <div class="gap">
                <video autoplay loop muted>
                    <source
                        src="https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/eg0c3th4vyjnnz09cwxam/22512-328261507_tiny.mp4?rlkey=sk0uvs93a3uby17qbzdx1c3cx&raw=1"
                        type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            live longer
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            and happier
            <div class="gap">
                <video autoplay loop muted>
                    <source
                        src="https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/eg0c3th4vyjnnz09cwxam/22512-328261507_tiny.mp4?rlkey=sk0uvs93a3uby17qbzdx1c3cx&raw=1"
                        type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



